# ことにする with causative

Tags: grammar, verbs, causation

> 私は子供に、自分のことは自分でさせる**ことにし**ている。
>
> 10時に駅で待ち合わせるという**ことにし**ませんか。

So in both the two sentences above, the causative form is used. Is this because the person speaking is talking to an inferior and giving orders? What would be accurate translations?

> 2週目に3日ぐらい出張する**ことになる**だろうと思います。

In this one, I don’t really understand why they use ことになる instead of ことになった. Wasn’t the decision that the person would be going on a business trip already decided in the past?

Thank you very much for your kind input.

Comment: +1, but 「待ち合わせる」 is not causative.  It is just the plain "dictionary" form.

Answer (score 2):

`dictionary-form + ことにする` means "to decide to ～", and `dictionary-form + ～ことにしている` means "I always ～", "It's my policy to ～", "I make a habit of ～ing", etc.

> - 私は子供に、自分のことは自分でさせることにしている。
>     It's my policy to make my child take care of himself. (lit. "make my child do his own things")
> - 10時に駅で待ち合わせるということにしませんか。
>     Shall (we) meet at the station at 10 o'clock then?

More examples here: https://www.renshuu.org/grammar/90

させる in the first sentence is a causative form, but it's not directly related to the ことにする construction. There is no causative form in the second sentence.

`dictionary-form + ことになる` means "it is determined/decided/arranged that ～", "to be going to ～" (due to some external cause out of the speaker's control), "to end up ～ing", etc.

> - 2週目に3日ぐらい出張することになるだろうと思います。
>     I think I'm (probably) going to make a business trip for a couple of days on the second week.

Note that he is just guessing his future. His business trip is not fixed yet, although he thinks it's very likely.